# Top label for matplotlib colorbars

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, colorbar, imshow

By default, matplotlib would position colorbar labels alongside the vertical colorbars. What is the best way to force the label to be on top of a colorbar? Currently my solution needs adjusting `labelpad` and `y` values depending on size of the label:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt 

dat = np.random.randn(10,10)
plt.imshow(dat, interpolation='none')

clb = plt.colorbar()
clb.set_label('label', labelpad=-40, y=1.05, rotation=0)

plt.show()
```

[image: colorbar top label]

Is there a better, more generic way to do this?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You could set the `title` of the colorbar axis (which appears above the axis), rather than the `label` (which appears along the long axis). To access the colorbar's `Axes`, you can use `clb.ax`. You can then use [`set_title`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_title), in the same way you can for any other `Axes` instance.

For example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt 

dat = np.random.randn(10,10)
plt.imshow(dat, interpolation='none')

clb = plt.colorbar()
clb.ax.set_title('This is a title')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: You can also `clb.ax.set_xlabel('Values')` to put it at bottom.

Answer (score 2):

Colorbars are stored in the list of Axes in the Figure. So colorbar title/label can be set by accessing the Axes containing the colorbar as well. Since it is an Axes object, `set()` method is defined on it which can be used to modify numerous properties such as title, xlabel, ylabel, ticks etc.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

dat = np.random.randn(10,10)
plt.imshow(dat, interpolation='none')
plt.colorbar()
plt.gcf().axes     # [<Axes: >, <Axes: label='<colorbar>'>]
plt.gcf().axes[1].set(title='This is a title', xlabel='caption', ylabel='colors');
```

Using subplots, the same plot can be coded as follows.

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(dat, interpolation='none')
fig.colorbar(ax.images[0], ax=ax)
fig.axes[1].set(title='This is a title', xlabel='caption', ylabel='colors');
```

[image: image2]